# StartActivity once user click Allow on Permission Screen

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

My one activity need Location Permission and I wrote below code to get permission. But in this case user need to click twice to open activity if app does not have location permission initially. Can I make some change so that once user click allow on Permission screen, only then intent fires.

```
 int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
                            String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[0];
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                                PERMISSIONS = new String[]{
                                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
                            }

                            if (!hasPermissions(getApplicationContext(), PERMISSIONS)) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(StartupActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
                            }

                            if (hasPermissions(getApplicationContext(), PERMISSIONS)) {
                                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, Details.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                }).start();
                            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to override `onRequestPermissionsResult`

First on `onCreate`

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[0];
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    PERMISSIONS = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
}

if (!hasPermissions(getApplicationContext(), PERMISSIONS)) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(StartupActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
}
```

then Override

```
  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_ALL) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this,Details.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`override` `onRequestPermissionsResult` and if the permission is granted then start your `Activity` from there

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == PERMISSION_ALL){
        if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){

             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, Details.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }).start();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Access Denied ! Cannot proceed further ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Note : Apparently , the code seems like in `StartupActivity` (from `StartupActivity.this` ) so you don't required to create a thread , simply start your `Details` `Activity` with simple `Intent`

---

Code will be

```
class StartupActivity extends ..{

    onCreate...(){}

    // here you will have onRequestPermissionsResult 
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult( ....){...}

}
```

Comment: code I gave is written in switch statement under case(1): Not getting @override onRequest method.

Comment: @Panache take a look at the update to get a visual hint to place your `onRequestPermissionsResult` code

Answer (score 0):

@Override
   onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[]     grantResults)
{

```
// Handle your permission grant/reject scenarios here, 
for( int x = 0; x < grantResults.length; x++ )
{
    if( grantResults[x] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
    {
         // Since you had one, start your new activity here
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something with the permissions that got BLOCKED??
    }
}
```

}

This will be internally called by android, once user grants/rejects a permission